# No module named 'python3-distutils'

Tags: python

При попытке установить пакет на убунту (раньше был на винде) вылазит ошибка

> No module named 'python3-distutils'

Команды `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils(-extra)` вызывают следующую ошибку:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
E: Невозможно найти пакет python3-distutils
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, в вашей версии Ubuntu пакет `python3-distutils` не доступен. Попробуйте установить пакет `python3-setuptools` вместо него:

`sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`

Если это не поможет, попробуйте обновить список пакетов:

`sudo apt-get update`

Если проблема не решится, попробуйте установить `python3-dev` и `build-essential`:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev build-essential`

Эти пакеты могут быть необходимы для установки других пакетов, включая `python3-distutils`.